# inserting select values into new attribute POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some data such as below:

```
full_name    

R Davies
N Powell
Harry S
A J Fulham
```

I want to split the name from the first space and insert the values into forename and surname. so it will look like below:

```
forename        surname

R               Davies
N               Powell
Harry           S
A               J Fulham
```

The code I have written is just to create the new columns and delete the old one. I have managed to create a select statement that will view the forename but I can't get it to insert.
So I need the code to insert both values into the new columns as well as get the surname.

```
ALTER TABLE names add forename varchar(100)
ALTER TABLE names add surname varchar(100)

UPDATE names
INSERT INTO names(forename)
SELECT split_part(full_name, ' ', 1) FROM names

ALTER TABLE names DROP COLUMN full_name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *only* want an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE names
   set forename = split_part(full_name, ' ', 1), 
       surname = split_part(full_name, ' ', 2)
```

`insert` is only used to create (insert) new *rows*.

Comment: Thank you kinda worked! It was able to put the values into the correct place but when a `full name` is `A J Fulham` or similar then the forename is `A` and the surname is just `J` is there a way to get all of the part after the first space?

Comment: @Unfitacorn: please create a new question for that.